# Firestore query array

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: database]
[image]

If I remove the `.whereArrayContainsAny("ItemID", Arrays.asList(onCart))` the statement, there is no error and it retrieves all the documents in a collection, but that is not what I want, I want to retrieve only the documents with `ItemID` value that is also in the onCart list `onCart` is from the intent of the prev activity.

> error msg: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported"

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    List<String> onCart=getIncomingIntent();
   
    loadCart(onCart);
}

private void loadCart(List<String> onCart) {
    db.collection("Items")
            .whereArrayContainsAny("ItemID", Arrays.asList(onCart))
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}


private List<String> getIncomingIntent() {
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("checkOut")) {
        return getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("checkOut");
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: `but the app crashes` If the app crashes, please find the exact error message and stack trace in its logcat output, and add them to your question (there's an edit link under it).

Comment: Also: "//this part does not work properly" What doesn't work about it? Don't you get any results? If so, can you edit your question to: 1) log the contents of `onCart`, 2) Show a screenshot of a document that you'd expect to get logged in `onComplete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i remove the .whereArrayContainsAny("ItemID", Arrays.asList(onCart)) statement, there is no error and it retrieves all the documents in a collection

That's the expected behavior since calling `.collection("Items")` along with `.get()` will return all documents within `Items` collection. However, when adding a call to:

```
.whereArrayContainsAny("ItemID", Arrays.asList(onCart))
```

It means that you are looking for every document where the `ItemID` field is an array that contains one of the elements that exist in the `onCart` array. This is actually no possible because your `ItemID` property is a String and **not** an array:

[image]

See the double quotes? If you need the functionality that the `whereArrayContainsAny()` method provides, you should change your `ItemID` property to be of type `array`. If you only want to check the values of your `onCart` array against your String property `ItemID`, then you should simply use:

```
.whereIn("ItemID", Arrays.asList(onCart));
```

This query returns every document where the `ItemID` field is set to one of the elements that exist in the `onCart` array.

Comment: thank you so much Alex, it finally worked using `.whereIn("ItemID",onCart)`